# Foreach em inner join

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, tenho uma consulta sql com inner join.

```
  $this->db->select('f.nome, f.sobrenome, h.habilidade');
  $this->db->from('funcionarios as f');
  $this->db->join('habilidades as h', 'f.id = h.id_funcionario');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

O retorno sql é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso listar esse retorno dizendo o nome do funcionário e as habilidades que ele tem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se eu pegar e dar um foreach assim:

```
foreach ($freelancers as $row){ 
  echo $row->nome; echo $row->sobrenome;
  echo $row->habilidade;
}
```

Ai ele pega e imprimir a mesma pessoa várias vezes, o que é natural. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é, qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Obs: Quero fazer de forma que não seja fazer 2 selects e usar foreach dentro de foreach com if.

Comment: "*Quero fazer de forma que não seja fazer 2 selects e usar foreach dentro de foreach com if*" por que não essas soluções?

Comment: Pq imagine que tenha 10 funcionário e cada 1 deles tenha 20 habilidades (embora na proposta será apresentada apenas 4 habilidades).

Ai você faz um foreach nos funcionários, e depois um foreach dentro das habilidades.

Isso daria: 10 x 20 = 200 repetições, isso não faz lá muita diferença de processamento

Agora imagine que seja 1000 funcionários.

1000 x 20 = 20 mil repetições ao invés de 1000 delas, o processamento acaba sendo torrada a cada vez que o sistema recebe novos dados.

Agora imagine que um sistema qualquer tenha 1 milhão de usuários com 20 habilidades.

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma função de agregação nas habilidades agrupando pelas colunas em comum e tratar o valor no PHP para exibição.

Comment: Mas sua tela exibirá 1000 (ou 1 milhão) de usuários de uma vez? Por que?

Comment: Qual função eu devo pesquisar para encontrar explicações sobre?

Comment: 1000 não, mas está perto de uns 700 funcionários, embora eu vá paginar para aparecer uns 10 ou 20 por vez

Comment: Exatamente. Então você não precisa se preocupar com o caso de processar 1000 de uma vez sendo que exibirá apenas 10 ou 20. É querer solucionar um problema que você não tem. Mas pode pesquisar pela `group_concat`. Spolier: você terá `foreach` dentro de `foreach`.

Comment: Uhn, vou pesquisar sobre o group_concat para entender sobre e vou testar o foreach com foreach na páginação e ver como vai ficar, obrigado pela atenção.